# select specific mesh when there are two meshes

Tags: mesh

[image: puzzle pieces]

I'd like to put the puzzle pieces together modify some vertices and then separate the two again. However when I try to select one of the puzzle pieces I can't cleanly select it because some of the faces aren't showing where the pieces connect I've tried to go inside the mesh and select the faces but I always seem to miss a bunch then when I use the move tool the unselected faces get stretched. What is the best way to connect the two puzzle pieces modify some vertices and then separate the two again?

Comment: Do you mean that you are joining them so that they are two separate mesh islands under one object, or are you using something like a boolean operation to fuse the faces of the mesh together?

Comment: If you want to grab one of the whole "pieces", select any part of it, and with your mouse over it press **L**

Comment: Thankyou Christopher Bennett!